# Counting the number of times an event occurs and reports it as well as the date of the session

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to create a sub that :

- records in a list how many times I pressed the return key **in the
  current session**
- I want my macro to write the numbers of times the return key was
  presssed in the session **on a new line each time I reopen the file**
- I also want my macro to record the files opening date and times on the
  same line

So, I want the first number of times the return key was pressed to be displayed in A2 (and then the date in B2). And then for the next session, go to the next row to write the next result in A3 and then the date in B3. And so on ...

Unfortunately, I am struggling. I have some issues regarding the event creation and the "go to the next line" process.

Here is the code I came out with :

```
Option Explicit
```

`Private Sub Return_Key()
    Application.OnKey "{RETURN}", "ReturnKeyCounter"
End Sub

Private Sub Session_Open()
    Workbook.Open "VBA_Exercice", "SessionOpened"
End Sub

Sub ReturnKeyCounter()

Feuil1.Cells(1, 1) = "Number of times"
Feuil1.Cells(1, 2) = "Session Date"

Set Column_Result = Feuil1.Cells(2, 1)
Set Column_Date = Feuil1.Cells(2, 2)

For Each Session_Open In Feuil3

    If Return_Key = True Then
    Counter = WorksheetFunction.Count(Return_Key)
    Column_Result.Offset(1, 0).Value = Counter
    Column_Date.Offset(1, 0).Value = Date

Next Session_Open

End Sub`

I hope someone will be able to help me out, thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want to include both the normal Return Key as well as the numeric keypad Return Key??

Comment: You are missing `End If` before Next `Session_Open`.

Comment: I just want to include the regular Return Key !

Comment: Thanks Vityata !